# Extract rows from data frame as list of vectors

Tags: r

For example, I have the data

```
a <- c("a", "b", "c")
b <- c("x", "y", "z")
df <- data.frame(a = a, b = b)
```

I want to do something to `df` so my result is

```
list(c("a", "x"), c("b", "y"), c("c", "z"))
```

I want the solution to be vectorized, and I'm having trouble utilizing the right *apply functions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to split up a data.frame by rows, try

```
 split(df, seq.int(nrow(df)))
```

Comment: It's obviously okay for the OP, but strictly this doesn't give the required result as per the question.

Comment: @thelatemail, it's an easy fix with `as.matrix`, no? `split(as.matrix(df), seq.int(nrow(df)))`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto - that'd do it, yep. Also `split(as.matrix(df),rownames(df))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way.

```
as.data.frame(t(df),stringsAsFactors=FALSE,row.names=NA)
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  a  b  c
# 2  x  y  z
```

This produces a data frame, which is in fact a list of vectors. If you must have a "true" list, you could use this:

```
as.list(as.data.frame(t(df),stringsAsFactors=FALSE,row.names=NA))
# $V1
# [1] "a" "x"
#
# $V2
# [1] "b" "y"
#
# $V3
# [1] "c" "z"
```